# Using static functions of different class in worker class for experimenting

Tags: c++, oop, static-methods

I have two classes which are inheriting from some virtual base class

```
class A : public BaseClass {
    public:
       static int foo(){ ... };

       static void bar(){ ... };
};

class B : BaseClass {
    public:
       static int foo(){ ... };

       static void bar(){ ... };
};
```

I have another class `Worker` that is exposed to the client and makes use of these two classes

```
class Worker{
    public:
       static void doFoo(){
           int result = A::foo();
           ...
       }

       static void doBar(){
           A::bar();
       }
}
```

I can either use `A` in the `Worker` class or `B`. Right now, if I have to plug the class `B` in `Worker` class, I will have to make changes in all the functions in the `Worker`.

```
class Worker{
    public:
       static void doFoo(){
           int result = B::foo();
           ...
       }

       static void doBar(){
           B::bar();
       }
}
```

Is there a way I can keep the methods static, not create an object of either `A`, `B`, or the `Worker` class and still be able to just make a few minor changes in the code and change the plug from `A` to `B`.

I thought of using templates (didn't explore it) but I don't want to let the user know of `A`, or `B`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a class template like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Worker_T {
    public:
       static void doFoo(){
           int result = T::foo();
       }

       static void doBar(){
           T::bar();
       }
};
```

and then to choose which class to actually use, you only have to choose one of the following:

```
using Worker = Worker_T<A>;
```

or

```
using Worker = Worker_T<B>;
```

and the user of `Worker` doesn't need to know about `A` or `B`.

Comment: This is great. Sorry, I am a cpp noob so this might come off as silly. But how do I expose just `Worker` to the user? If I include the entire file, the user will get to know about Worker_T, A, and B?

Comment: You can't actually prevent users from knowing about those classes. However a common approach is to put all the implementation details into a `details` namespace. Also, you can move the implementation code to another header file, so that users have to dig a little to know about it.